# Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int\limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}g = \frac{\log ^2(n)}{2 \log (10)}|_a^b$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, number-theory, applications, stieltjes-integral

I'm having trouble with this integral:

$\int\limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}g = \frac{\log ^2(n)}{2 \log (10)}|_a^b$

If I want to find the product such:

$10^m.10^{m+1}...\leq n$

so for example for $n=100$ this would be $10^1.10^2=1000$

I derived a Riemann-Stieltjes integral to approximate this problem as follows:

Consider $\int\limits_a^b \color{red}{f(x)} \, \color{blue}{\mathrm{d}g}$ where $\color{red}{f(x)}=\log(x)$ and ${\color{blue}{\mathrm{d}g} = \frac{1}{n \log (10)}}$

since $\log _{10}(x)$ gives the number of 10's $\leq$ x.

Therefore $\begin{align}\int\limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}g  =  \frac{\log ^2(n)}{2 \log (10)}|_a^b             \tag{1}\end{align}$

Is this correct?

**Part 2:**

Assuming that question 1 is correct, then plotting the log product of powers of ten results in the staircase (purple) shown in the log graph below.

Why does (1) (shown blue) not correspond but is exactly halfway between $n-1$ and $n$?

[image: 10's]

mathematica

```
Ten[n_] := Product[10^i, {i, Log[10, n]}];
DiscretePlot[{Log[n]^2/(2 Log[10]), Log[Ten[n]]},(**){n, 1, 1001, 1}]
```

Comment: How is the function $g(x)$ defined?

Comment: @Maxim I suppose $\int_1 \frac{1}{n \log (10)}$

Comment: I do not follow. You need to specify the function $g(x)$, which is just an ordinary real-valued function. Changing the value of $g$ *just at an endpoint* can change the value of the integral, so you need to be precise in your definition. The integral in your comment is missing the upper limit and the differential.

Comment: @Maxim checking back through my notes I actually used $g(x)=\log _{10}(x)$ the end point was the same as the maximum (b) of the range I was interested in $\begin{align}\int\limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}g  =  \frac{\log ^2(n)}{2 \log (10)}|_a^b             \tag{1}\end{align}$

Comment: I don't understand the problem, in particular, what $m$ is and why you need the Riemann-Stieltjes integral. If $n = 10^k$, then $\ln \prod_{i = 1}^k 10^i = k (k + 1) \ln(10) / 2$, while $\ln^2(10^k)/(2 \ln 10) = k^2 \ln(10)/2$, which explains the plots. If $g(x)$ is continuously differentiable, you simply have $\int_a^b f(x) d g(x) = \int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx$.

Comment: @Maxim the $m$ is for ascending powers that make the LHS $\leq$ to the RHS. The reason why I need Riemann-Steiljes is $[\log _{10}(x)]$ gives the number of 10's ≤ x which are discrete steps so I thought Riemann-

Steiltjes would suitable to find the product of the power of tens less than or equal to x. Now I 

thought ...

Comment: $\log _{10}(x)$ would make a good estimate just like d(Li(x)) does with $d(Pi(x)$ in number theory for working out the Chebychev theta fuction shown here http://math.tufts.edu/faculty/rlemkeoliver/teaching/250/02-RiemannStieltjes.pdf

. So I was attempting to do the same but for powers of ten that are discetely distributed. So that's the first question in the question which I think you've just answered that what I have done is not correct but there should be a way to do this with Reimann-Steiltjes integral I hope.

Comment: If the first factor is always $10^1$, then $P = \prod_{k = 1}^{\lfloor \log_{10} K \rfloor} 10^k = 10^{\lfloor \log_{10} K \rfloor (\lfloor \log_{10} K \rfloor + 1)}$. Then you can solve the inequality $P < n$ wrt the variable $\lfloor \log_{10} K \rfloor$. It's still not clear to me whether or not this is the problem that you're solving and what $m$ is here.